# Setting an outlook email subject up with 2 sets of quotes

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

Outlook in VBA issue

I attempted to use the above code to have a macro set up an email subject saying Something like "X 8/14 - 8/20"

However when I attempt to use two sets of quotes there is an error

```
Sub Sales_Report()

'For Tips see: http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/winmail/Outlook/tips.htm
'Don't forget to copy the function RangetoHTML in the module.
'Working in Excel 2000-2016
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object

    Set rng = Nothing
    On Error Resume Next
    'Only the visible cells in the selection
    Set rng = Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    'You can also use a fixed range if you want
    'Set rng = Sheets("YourSheet").Range("D4:D12").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If rng Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "The selection is not a range or the sheet is protected" & _
               vbNewLine & "please correct and try again.", vbOKOnly
        Exit Sub
    End If

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .To = ""
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        **.Subject = "X" & Date - 7 & Date - 1**
        .HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(rng)
        .Display
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Two sets of quotes? I see where you are setting `.Subject` and it is working just fine - it returns `X8/15/20198/21/2019` - is that what you wanted? if not, then please clarify your question.

Answer (score 0):

try it like this:

```
.Subject = "X " & DateAdd("d", -7, Date) & " - " & DateAdd("d", -1, Date)
```

Using `DateAdd` to subtract 7 days, if that is what you wanted to subtract.